# Fix texture UV after editing the mesh?

Tags: uv

How to fix 'broken' texture when extruding a mesh? I want to manually move the selected face into appropriate texture image, but it got in a little weird tangling with other vertices as seen in image2.

[image: edited mesh]

[image: uv]

Comment: Hello it's not clear what you are trying to do, do you mean that you've extruded your object in the 3D scene? Please show the object before and tell a bit more?

Comment: basically, I just extruded one of the faces and the texture does not automatically there, I want to know how to fill the new faces with the texture. The base object is a box.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the *Transform Correct Face Attibutes* option, it will automatically change the UVs in the *UV Editor* and therefore extend the texture on your object:

[image]

[image]